# Laravel 8 Tests: PHPUnit error: Unknown formatter "unique"

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I have written a test that involves a factory. When I execute the test, I get this error:

> The data provider specified for Tests\Unit\ExampleTest::testTakePlace is invalid. InvalidArgumentException: Unknown formatter "unique" /var/www/html/api/vendor/fakerphp/faker/src/Faker/Generator.php:249

## Expected result

This error should not be shown, I should be able to use `$this->faker->unique()`.

## How I tried to fix this problem

By reading the doc again and again (no difference was found) and by reading questions&answers on the Internet (only one question & only one answer were found: to extend Laravel's `TestCase` but the official documentation, as I mentionned it, says the contrary). (Laravel's `TestCase` is provided by `use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase;`)

## Question

Why doesn't it work and how to fix this bug?

## Sources

### Test sources

It extends `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` (not Laravel's `TestCase`) because the documentation says to extend it. Indeed: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/testing#creating-and-running-tests . This is not the only part of the doc mentionning to extend it.

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use App\Models\Project;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider provideTakePlaceData
     */
    public function testTakePlace($project)
    {
        $response = $this->json('GET', '/controllerUserProject_takePlace', [
            'project_id' => $project->id
        ]);

        
    }
    
    public function provideTakePlaceData() {
        return [    
                    Project::factory()->make()
        ];
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ControllerUserProject extends Controller
{
    public function takePlace(Request $request, $project_id)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

### The most important: the factory

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Project;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class ProjectFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Project::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
                    'id' => $this->faker->unique()->numberBetween(1, 9000), 
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: You should extend the TestCase from Laravel, this TestCase also extends the PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase, so you will have Laravel methods & PhpUnit methods. Try

Comment: Run `composer update` to make sure everything's up to date? If this project was created in an older version of Laravel, make sure your `composer.json` has been updated to match [the latest one](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/composer.json), which uses a different faker library.

Comment: I can use the same code in my factory without problem (although I don't; I just let the DB autoincrement take care of primary keys for me.) Is there a reason your question spends so much time on the testing aspect? Does the factory work in other contexts?

Comment: @miken32 what command did you use? `php artisan test` ?

Comment: I was just testing the factory code alone, but it looks like it was a wider issue for you.

Answer (score 11):

Change:
`use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;`
to:
`use Tests\TestCase;`

Why?

When your `ExampleTest` extends `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` Laravel app is never initialized in tests, and so you don't have access to Laravel features like factories.

The documentation tells you to extend `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;`, but it refers to Unit tests. Feature tests should extend `Tests\TestCase`. This is something pretty new. Until Laravel 5.8 both unit and feature tests were extending `Tests\TestCase` by default. I personally just define all tests as feature tests to avoid such issues.

Comment: I'm using a Unit Test. Even when extending `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` , I can't use factories in data providers.

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler I see what you mean now exactly. It will work, if you call `$this->refreshApplication();` inside the data provider. But you'd still need to extend the `Tests\TestCase`.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense because you can do a pure unit test in isolation from the framework,  thank you for this explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was due to the use of a `dataProvider` with the use of the factories. More precisely: PHPUnit data providers should not be used when Laravel factories are.

Comment: I wonder how are you then supposed to put objects in data providers without typing them all out by hand.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are using faker in Factories please make sure these are working correctly regardless (as per example try running `Project::factory()->make();` within Laravel Tinker and see the results)
2. Second common issue (as mentioned above) is the class that you extend your Test with - see above
3. Third and frequently omitted one that's causing this error, is a missing parent constructor call in the setUp() - (if you use it)

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;
use App\Models\Project;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    protected Project $project;

    public function setUp(): void
    { 
         parent::setUp();
         $this->project = Project::factory()->make();
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to use the WithFaker trait to use faker :

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use App\Models\Project;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
     use WithFaker;
     
     // ...
 }
```

Comment: It doesn't work, same problem :) I'm going to try to extend from Laravel. (use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase;
)

Comment: Edit: `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase` makes me to implement an abstract method. It's definitely different from what I've read in the official documentation (link given in the OP)

Comment: Btw https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#writing-factories says there isn't need for using `WithFaker`